# C++ How to find if the next character to be std::cout will be at the start of the console line

Tags: c++, console, std, cout

Okay so what I want to know is if there is a way to detect of finding if the next char typed will be at the start of the line in the console e.g. the far left

Comment: In general you can't. Ncurses will probably help you if we are talking linux.

Comment: Normally, input is held by the console emulator until the user types the `ENTER` key (or whatever EOF happens to be mapped to), so "the next char typed" has probably already been typed, if by that you mean the next character which you will read. That might not be the case if you're using ncurses or conio, in which case you should clarify your question by describing how you are reading from the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay figured it out, all you gotta do is this then ask if it equals 0.

```
    int wherex()
    {
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi))
            return -1;
        return csbi.dwCursorPosition.X;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was really interested in seeing what the answer would be